# Xcode Parse.com save to csv/any file?

Tags: ios, xcode, csv, parse-platform

I pretty much finished my project. It's ticket booking app based on Parse.com written in objective c in Xcode. Also i want to mention i'm pretty new in objective C world.

One functionality is TableView which shows user his order history, it is followed by ViewController which shows orders details.

Now one of requirements of this app was "save and load data". My lecturer says that it HAS to have this function(no matter if it's really that useful). So i figured i could make "save" for order history. Then when app has no access to internet user could load csv file(previously saved) and look up his order history with details(again in tableview > view controller).

I'm pretty tired and i have no idea how to come around this. I think that best file format would be CSV, but i've never worked with these in Xcode. I'm looking for any advice or an idea on how to handle that.

Comment: Because this is Objective-C, the easiest solution for dealing with file saving and loading is probably a plist rather than CSV. Objective-C has native support for plist handling, and serialisation of arrays, dictionaries, and other simple object types (string, number, data etc) is supported, as well as more complex/custom types if you build your own serialisation support via NSCoding. You can read more about creating and reading plists at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i

Comment: Holy moly! I have to dig into that. Thanks for advice.